# Doctrine2: how to solve left join not being generated

Tags: doctrine-orm

consider these two entities:

```
/** @Entity  */
class String {
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    public $id;

    /** @Column(length=255) */
    public $name;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="StringTranslation", mappedBy="owner") */
    public $translations;
}

/** @Entity */
class StringTranslation {
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    public $id;

    /* @ManyToOne(targetEntity="String", inversedBy="translations")
     * @JoinColumn(name="foreignId", referencedColumnName="id") */
    public $owner;

    /** @Column(length=2) */
    public $lang;

    /** @Column(length=255) */
    public $translation;
}
```

When I get the query using

```
$query = qb()->select(array('s', 't'))
    ->from('String', 's')
    ->leftJoin('s.translations', 't')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSQL();
```

I get this result:

> SELECT s0_.id AS id0, s0_.name AS name1, s1_.id AS id2, s1_.foreign_id
>   AS foreign_id3, s1_.lang AS lang4, s1_.translation AS translation5
>   FROM String s0_ LEFT JOIN

Why is the left join not being generated?

When i try to get the result of the query with

```
$query = qb()->select(array('s', 't'))
    ->from('String', 's')
    ->leftJoin('s.translations', 't')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getArrayResult();
```

this error comes up:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Have you validated your schema using `orm:validate-schema`?

Comment: I'm new to doctrine so I'm figuring out how to run `orm:validate schema`. When I use the Schematool to generate schemasql it outputs 
`array(
[0] =>
'CREATE TABLE String (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = InnoDB'
[1] =>
'CREATE TABLE StringTranslation (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, lang VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL, translation LONGTEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = InnoDB'
)`   The foreignId column in StringTranslation seems to be missing even though I specified it in de JoinColumn annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! It all boils down to a typo. Annotations must start with `/**` and not with `/*`. Changing the line

```
/* @ManyToOne(targetEntity="String", inversedBy="translations")
```

to

```
/** @ManyToOne(targetEntity="String", inversedBy="translations")
```

solved the problem!